# C# Autolevel snippet?

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, image-manipulation

Has anyone seen any good snippets for autoleveling an image in C#?

Answer (score 6):

See http://code.google.com/p/aforge/

Comment: You should make this as the answer, if the question has been resolved.

Answer (score 3):

The [source code for Paint.net](http://www.afterdawn.com/software/source_codes/paint.net.cfm#) might be a good place to rummage around for various examples of image processing with .NET. In fact, auto-level is a basic feature of Paint.NET, you just need to dig it out!